# Teamcity and subversion

Tags: svn, teamcity, hgsubversion

I have a teamcity server that belong to our group.
I built a project that reference Subversion source control.
and I made the trigger to be associated with subversion.
The subversion doesn't belong to our group.
It was working fine, until the group who own subversion, did some upgrade (which I am not sure what exactly)
After that our teamcity server stopped being triggered by the checkin into subversion.

Is there a log file for teamcity where I can check what is failing?
 I checked Windows Event Viewer but there was no error at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TeamCity logfiles are located in the "logs" folder below your TeamCity installation. There you can find a teamcity-vcs.log and a teamcity-svn.log containing log information about VCS operations. You could also try to go into Version control settings for your build configuration and use the "Test connection" button at the bottom, to see if something is preventing TeamCity from accessing your SVN server.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen TeamCity's "Test Conntection" to be pretty useful to diagnose these kind of issues. Also, try accessing SVN through the login that TeamCity uses.